# Is there a bug with getPart method?

Tags: servlets

I am using Servlet 3.1, and when a MultipartConfig condition is violated (eg: maxFileSize), calling request.getParameter() returns null for normal form fields.

I saw that another guy faced this kind of issue:

> With Servlet 3.0, if a MultipartConfig condition is violated (eg: maxFileSize), calling request.getParameter() returns null. Is this on purpose? What if I get some regular (text) parameters before calling getPart (and checking for an IllegalStateException)? This causes a NullPointerException to be thrown before I have a chance to check for the IllegalStateException

Is there a bug with getPart method?

Thanks